# CASE...THEN SELECT AS to produce multiple columns based on condition

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to split up the video_views column into multiple columns based on the date using a SWITCH CASE statement, but this doesn't seem to be achieving the desired results.

```
SELECT video_views AS
CASE
  WHEN date >= '2020-01-01' AND date <= '2020-12-31' THEN video_views END AS video_views_20
  WHEN date >= '2021-01-01' AND date <= '2021-12-31' THEN video_views END AS video_views_21
  WHEN date >= '2022-01-01' AND date <= '2022-12-31' THEN video_views END AS video_views_22
FROM `table_name'
```

I expect 3 columns to be produced based on the chosen date ranges.

Comment: A case expression returns one value only. (For its first WHEN condition evaluating to TRUE.) If you want 3 columns, you need 3 case expressions.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result. Seems like you need multiple case constructs and likely also have to use an aggregate function, but it's pure guessing without any further information.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.